# Youtube - embed with high quality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, embed

I have created an introduction video for my application to youtube and I can't embed it in my application home [page](http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo) (try to play the video without changing quality settings) in high quality by default. Video is useless in lower than 720p since it displays navigation through my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 720p (if available), add `&vq=hd720` to the end of your video url.

```
www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEO_CODE>/?vq=hd720
```

Similarly, `&vq=hd1080` will force 1080p (if available).

Comment: It worked, I had to use iframe though: http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo Thank you!